# Error sending e-mail via SMTP server on App Engine development server

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I am trying to send Email using [this sample code](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html) and these command-line options:

```
dev_appserver.py --smtp_host=smtp.gmail.com --smtp_port=25 --smtp_user=xxx@gmail.com--smtp_password=k1tt3ns myapp
```

However, I receive the following error when my app tries to send e-mail (on the development server):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 500, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\desk\Desktop\apps\temp\main.py", line 139, in post
    """)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail.py", line 205, in send_mail
    message.send(make_sync_call)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail.py", line 474, in send
    make_sync_call('mail', self._API_CALL, message, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 68, in MakeSyncCall
    apiproxy.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 240, in MakeSyncCall
    stub.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub.py", line 80, in MakeSyncCall
    method(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail_stub.py", line 203, in _Send
    self._SendSMTP(mime_message, smtp_lib)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail_stub.py", line 133, in _SendSMTP
    smtp.login(self._smtp_user, self._smtp_password)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\smtplib.py", line 552, in login
    raise SMTPException("SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

Comment: First make sure your ISP allows you to use a third-party SMTP server for sending emails. Most do, but some providers will block access to SMTP servers to make sure their customers won't start spamming the World.

Answer (score 18):

dev_appserver.py doesn't support TLS which is required by Gmail. You can enable it by adding a few lines in api/mail_stub.py:

```
# After smtp.connect(self._smtp_host, self._smtp_port)
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
smtp.ehlo()
```

**Note!** That's the quick and dirty solution. You should add some kind of flag to tell it whether you want to use TLS or not, as it is not always desired.

Comment: hi Blixt, Thanks for u given solution of my request , with the above changes it was working fine... same as gmail, my company is one domain in Google, with the changes of my company details its not working .. means in place of gmail I given my company name... is it correct?
as u said above solution is not preferred one what could be the correct solution.

Comment: and then in deploy, it still works? i don't think I can edit a file from the google app engine api sdk

Comment: Yes. The mail API live is configured by Google themselves so you don't need to worry about how the connection to mail servers is made.

Comment: @Blixt. I think this workaround may have stopped working. At least, it has for me in the latest dev_appserver 1.8.6. If you had in your heart to check out my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680910/smtpsenderrefused-when-sending-mail-from-gae-dev-appserver-on-gmail) about it I would owe you 1 million upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

@Raymond

Execute the following command in the Terminal:

```
find / -name "mail_stub.py" -type f 2>/dev/null
```

In my case it returns:

```
/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/mail_stub.py
```

Answer (score 0):

The other methods are no longer necessary:

Setting the following in `/appengine/api/mail_stub.py`

```
if self._allow_tls and smtp.has_extn ('STARTTLS'):
  smtp.starttls ()
```

works for me on appengine sdk version 1.9.15

Answer (score 0):

The Google account being used to send emails from an application must have some security settings disabled in https://security.google.com/settings.

- Disable access for less secure apps :
  Access for less secure apps: Turn On

If you continue to have authentication issues you may have to review the Devices &  activity at the https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking up this answer in 2018 or later: this workaround is no longer needed. You can now use the command like the original poster wrote it:

```
dev_appserver.py --smtp_host=smtp.gmail.com --smtp_port=25 --smtp_user=xxx@gmail.com --smtp_password=yyy myapp
```