# Sending email from dev server with --smtp_host=smtp.gmail.com

Tags: google-app-engine, smtp

In the answer to the question [Error sending e-mail via SMTP server on App Engine development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968445/error-sending-e-mail-via-smtp-server-on-app-engine-development-server) there is a [nice solution by Blixt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968445/error-sending-e-mail-via-smtp-server-on-app-engine-development-server/968507#968507):

```
"dev_appserver.py does not support TLS 
which is required by Gmail. You can 
enable it by adding a few lines in api/mail_stub.py:"

# After smtp.connect(self._smtp_host, self._smtp_port)
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
smtp.ehlo()
```

But windows Vista would not let me change `api/mail_stub.py`

Is there another way to send mail from development server. Other options (Sendmail and ISP are not good for me). Thanks!

**EDIT**

I changed the `api/mail_stub.py` according to instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968445/error-sending-e-mail-via-smtp-server-on-app-engine-development-server) and I use the following command-line options:

```
dev_appserver.py  
--smtp_host=smtp.gmail.com 
--smtp_port=25 
--smtp_user=xxxx@gmail.com 
--smtp_password=gmail_pw 
C:\Users\A\Desktop\repeater # path to root directory
```

But I get this error from Log Console:

```
***********************************************************
2010-11-18 10:24:37 Running command: "['C:\\Python26\\pythonw.exe', 
'C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', 
'--admin_console_server=', 
'--port=8080', 
u'dev_appserver.py', 
u'--smtp_host=smtp.gmail.com', 
u'--smtp_port=25', 
u'--smtp_user=xxxx@gmail.com', 
u'--smtp_password=gmail_pw 
C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\repeater', 
'C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\repeater']"

Runs a development application server for an application.

dev_appserver.py [options] <application root>

Application root must be the path to the application to run in this server.
Must contain a valid app.yaml or app.yml file.

****************************************************
```

This is the app.yaml:

```
application: re-peater
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
  upload: static/images/favicon.ico

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /.*
  script: repeater.py
```

All this works without these command line options. Any suggestions why this is not working?

Comment: I see two problems. First is use of port 25. Gmail authenticates only over an encrypted connection. Try 587, as it seems to work when port 465 won't. It may have something to do with STARTTLS. And TLS must be enabled via command-line arg to dev_appserver.py. If that's clear as mud, then it accurately reflects the state of SMTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really, really need to send real email from the dev_appserver, you should set up your own mail relay on your machine, and point the SDK at that. I'm curious why it's so important to send real email, though - this is the development server, and you shouldn't be using it for anything other than development.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I agree. But I am still learning the basics and it takes time and trial and error to make even the simple tasks work. For instance I have this simple script posted here http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/42e046e858c87aa3?hl=en# and even that simple script does not work the way I imagine it would work. So, I deploy that script and see if it sends the email. And now app engine is down and I get 500 errors. But you are right, probably it is not worth making the dev server send emails. I will keep uploading to the app engine until it works.

Comment: Wait what's wrong with sending a real email to a test email address while in development?

Comment: @Triptych Nothing - it's just a lot of work to get it working correctly, since you need a relay that'll accept the message. It's generally easier to look at the console output.

Comment: @NickJohnson it's harder to test the console output programmatically, since it might be cluttered with other log messages.  Some way to receive the email programmatically is important (to me) so I can automate testing~

Answer (score 1):

Change the file permissions so that you can change the `api/mail_stub.py` file.

Comment: I tried changing the file permissions but Vista will not allow that. http://www.vistax64.com/vista-file-management/29148-vista-forces-read-only-file-setting.html

Comment: I changed the file but I get an error message with a problem to the root directory. Without these command line options the dev server works fine; app.yaml is in the directory. Any ideas why this is not working? I added an EDIT above with more code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer necessary

in /appengine/api/mail_stub.py

`if self._allow_tls and smtp.has_extn ('STARTTLS'):
  smtp.starttls ()`

I am using appengine sdk version 1.9.15.