# SMTP email on GAE dev server - how? Python 2.5.4, GAE SDK 1.7.4

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gmail

Attempting to test email functionality locally.

The following options are enabled when I launch dev server:
`--smtp_host=smtp.gmail.com --smtp_user=myemailadress@gmail.com --smtp_password=whatever`

Results in the following exceptions:

`ERROR    2013-01-17 13:35:34,621 _webapp25.py:468] This class/method is not available.`
`File "C:\Python25\lib\socket.py", line 387, in readline
    buf.write(buffer(data, 0, nl))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 884, in NotImplementedFake
    raise NotImplementedError('This class/method is not available.')
NotImplementedError: This class/method is not available.`

How can I test email functionality from local dev server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got it to work, but:

a) had to use Python 26 when running dev server

b) manually hacked the mail_stub.py file as per this S/O answer: [Error sending e-mail via SMTP server on App Engine development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968445/error-sending-e-mail-via-smtp-server-on-app-engine-development-server)